# Auto-Load a html table with combobox

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, html-table

I want to load different html tables when I select an option in my combobox.
For example if I have a combobox with 4 categories (Cars, Bikes, Motorbikes and Airplanes) I would like that when I select one of the options, the specific table loads... and the tables may be different in size (not all the tables are for example 3 rows and 3 cells, each one of the tables may not be the same in structure)

```
 <select name="um" id="um" class="select_opt">
 <option value="Car">Car</option>"
 <option value="Bike">Bike</option>"
 <option value="Motorbike">Motorbike</option>"
 <option value="Airplane">Airplane</option>"

 <table id="Car" cellspacing="0">

   <tr>
  <th scope="alt">Title 1</th>
   </tr>  
   <tr>
     <td>Something 1</td>
     <td>Something 2</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

I have the combobox and one of the tables, I would like to see that table when I select the "Car" option... the same with the rest of the options in the combobox.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you at least set up a data structure of some sort for your combobox data?

Comment: I have the combobox with the options and I already have one table that suits one option of the combobox options... my idea is that when I select other option the proper table get loaded.

Comment: Please post some of your code, otherwise answers will be very general.

Comment: I added an example of the code that I have now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are *two* ways to do this, one with pure JavaScript (no library) and the other using jQuery.

The process involves hiding all the tables then based on the value of the selected option choose the correct table to show.

The example tables have various columns (1-4) since you mentioned your tables may be various sizes as well.

**JavaScript only:**

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/wUncy/1/)

```
var tables = [
    document.getElementById('Car'),
    document.getElementById('Bike'),
    document.getElementById('Motorbike'),
    document.getElementById('Airplane')
];

document.getElementById('um').onchange = function() {
    // hide all tables
    for (var i in tables) {
        tables[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    // get selected value and show it's table
    var selectedValue = this[this.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue) {
        document.getElementById(selectedValue).style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

**jQuery:**

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/wUncy/)

```
// reuse variable to hide all tables
var $tables = $('table');

// Combobox change event
$('.select_opt').change(function() {
    $tables.hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

Comment: wooow man, many thx really!
so quick and detailed response... with examples too!
u r god :P
thx again.

Comment: Im having a javascript conflict :S
After I select a second option and the table is displayed all my javascript functions doesnt work anymore (like one function that displays the date)
What can be happening?

Comment: @dan do you have a jsfiddle example you can show with this issue?